# Scraping data streamed via web-sockets off website using phantomjs or node

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to scrape data off a website. This data is rendered on an HTML Canvas on the website and continually updated. As I understand, one cannot scrape the data off the canvas element since it's more or less a graphic. But the fact remains that this data is being streamed to my browsers so using a headless JavaScript engine such as PhantomJS or NodeJS I ought to be able to get access to the raw data coming off the web socket. 
I have scraped sites using PhantomJS but I'm unable to find a way to get to this raw data coming via the web socket. I am loading the page using PhantomJS, it get's loaded but obviously the page opens a new connection to connect to the web socket on the origin server and starts receiving a feed. How can my PhantomJS script hook into it?

Thanks.

Comment: The bad news is that it would be very hard to do it with phantomjs, the good news is that it should be easy to do with node.js using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws to connect to the websocket directly.  I'd start by inspecting the WS frames in chrome.

Comment: Thanks - not sure who downvoted the question and for what reason.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS 1.x doesn't support web sockets. PhantomJS 2 is still not out.

If the site actually works in PhantomJS then there is probably some fallback in which case you can use `page.onResourceReceived` to register to an event and scrape some meta data. The event listener doesn't expose resource data. Since the fallback is probably stateful, you can't actually scrape it with custom XHRs.